# How can I find the middle element of the list in a function in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I need some help in Haskell. I'm new to haskell. I want to find middle element of the list but I want to do this in a function. I tried to find length of list and division to 2. But I failed to get length of list as int in a function.

```
findListL k = [z | let z = length k]
```

I tried the code at the top but I failed.
Can Someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What if the list has an even number of elements, like `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: Au contraire, you succeeded in getting the length of the list as an int in a function. Good job! It's just that getting that is only part of the goal. Can you say in words what you were hoping to do once you had the length? We may be able to help you identify existing functions (or write your own) that accomplish concrete goals, once you have a plan. (And, by the way, the answer to the direct question you asked, "Can someone tell me how to do it?" is: "No, we are not going to do your work for you.".)

Comment: My goal was to get the length of the list as int, not as a list. I mentioned that in my question. I stated that if you read my question, I could not find the length of the list, and if I found it, I would divide it by 2 and reach my result. I learned a different approach in the incoming solution, which was a new learning for me.

Comment: @fs45: Did you try just writing `length k` instead of wrapping it in a list? `findListL k = [z | let z = length k]` is the same as `findListL k = [length k]`, and if you don’t want the result to be wrapped in a list, then you could omit the list, writing `findListL k = length k` instead. To divide this length in half, you probably want ``length k `div` 2``, for integer division which rounds down, or `fromIntegral (length k) / 2` for fractional division, in which `fromIntegral` converts from `Int` to a fractional type such as `Float` or `Double`. `Int` doesn’t have fractional division `(/)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can approach this problem with a tortoise and hare approach. We concurrently iterate with two iterators over the same list. The hare each time takes two steps, whereas the tortoise moves one step forward. If the hare reaches the end, then the tortoise is in the middle. We can thus implement this as:

```
findListL :: [a] -> a
findListL zs = go zs zs
  where go (_:_:xs) ~(_:ys) = go xs ys
        go _ (y:_) = y
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude> findListL []
*** Exception: <interactive>:(3,9)-(4,22): Non-exhaustive patterns in function go
Prelude> findListL [1]
1
Prelude> findListL [1,2]
2
Prelude> findListL [1,2,3]
2
Prelude> findListL [1,2,3,4]
3
```

For an empty list, this will raise an error, for a list with an even length, it will take the element at index `(n+1)/2`.

Since the computation for an empty list does not work, one often constructs a function that returns a `Maybe a`, and thus a `Just y` in case we found an element `y` in the middle, and a `Nothing` in case the list is empty. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: From this perspective I hadn't thought. I was trying to do it with a length calculation. Thank you for the reply. It was the result I wanted to achieve, but I couldn't.